I can't access the designer for c1truedbgrid. The ‘designer’ is not present in the context menu. Running Windows 11, VS 2019 or 2022 VB .net
I have a very large app with Component One Grids in several projects.  It appears I am no longer able to access the grid designer from the form.  I have a reference to the c1.win.c1truedbgrid dll in my project references.  What am I missing? I need to edit the grids.  Code is VB.net Framework 4.7.2  VS 2019 & 2022.  neither seem to work
Not sure what else to look at.  Is this a windows 11 issue?  I have a new system as of a few months ago.

No prior knowledge about ComponentOne but it requires a paid license for development. Are you a paying customer? If so, contact the vendor for support - you pay for that. If not, then maybe that's your answer.

In addition to djv's comment, if you aren't using version control yet, a few months ago would have been a good time to start using it. However, do you have backups of the projects that you could use to go back to before it broke?

@dvj  yes  it is licensed.

@AndrewMorton  I pulled down some older code.  This app for several years old.   same result.  seems to be a windows 11 issue.  But I can not find any reference or issue.

I have no knowledge of this component, but the designer code may be housed in a separate library that is no longer in the same directory as the referenced "c1.win.c1truedbgrid.dll".  Following typical naming conventions, this library would be named "c1.win.c1truedbgrid.Design.dll" .
